# Angular ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with @Input() to child views

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have a child view with content

```
export class ChildViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() loading = true;
}
```

and parent component like

```
export class ParentViewComponent implements OnInit {
  loading = true;

  getList() {
    this.myService.getList().subscribe(() => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

and `parent-view.component.html`

```
<app-child-view [loading]="loading"></app-child-view>
```

But when `loading` values changes, it gives error

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'loading: true'. Current value: 'loading: false'.
```

Comment: When is `getList()` method called in `ParentViewComponent` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to child component

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    ...
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: I had to add `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` to the `@component` decorator, for `ChangeDetectorRef` to work.